# scanf not recognizing format %zu

Tags: c, scanf

**I have the following code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const int* x = a, *y = b;
    if (*x < *y)
        return -1;
    else if (*x == *y)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int main()
{
    size_t n;
    printf("Enter number of numbers: ");
    scanf("%zu", &n); //<-- warnings here
    int numbers[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number #%zu: ", i + 1); //NO warning here, printf works as expected
        scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
    }
    qsort(numbers, n, sizeof *numbers, compare);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
    printf("\n");
    system("pause"); //don't comment for this, I know it's bad
}
```

**I get 2 warnings from my GCC compiler:**

```
warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

I have set GCC to C11. Can anybody help me understand why I am getting this?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that my code still works, even with those warnings, however it is very strange as to me it seems that variable n is not getting its value from scanf

Comment: Are you using mingw? The MS C runtime is known to not support many C99 features.

Comment: mingw shows those warnings. So if you want to use it and be portable - conditional compiletion is needed

Comment: I am using MinGW but I don't know how to check my compiler version (if I run `gcc --version` in command prompt it says 2.95 so I don't think it is that one).

Comment: @DarkAtom it is correct version. minGW simple does not support it.

Comment: By the way, @kaylum, the code compiles fine in VS if you replace the VLA with a dynamic array.

Comment: @DarkAtom *"if I run gcc --version in command prompt it says 2.95"* 2.95 was released in 1999! Where did you even find it? Go get a version from this millennium. :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I downloaded GCC 9.2.0 and it compiles the code fine, but I don't know how to integrate it into my IDE and so I cannot see if it throws those warnings anymore.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Code::Blocks (version 17.12, if that matters)

Comment: @DarkAtom It should be possible to integrate it. I've not used CB for a while, but when I did, GCC 7 or 8 did work for me, I don't see why GCC 9 wouldn't. Make sure you specify a correct compiler path in the CB compiler settings, and that it doesn't contain spaces and/or non-ascii symbols, and all that.

Comment: Ok, it worked, but it made it worse :( Now it throws warnings for both the `scanf` and the `printf` that contains `%zu`. Actually I get 2 sets of warnings for each! (8 warnings in total)

Comment: @DarkAtom Try this flag: `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1`.

Comment: Where should I put that? Putting it in the compiler flags (along with `-std=c11`) doesn't make any difference. Sorry, but I am quite a noob when it comes to compiler options and that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't know how to check my compiler version

A common test involves `__STDC__, __STDC_VERSION__`.  Something like:

```
#if defined __STDC__
  #if defined __STDC_VERSION__ && __STDC_VERSION__ > 201710
    // New
    #error Time to update this code
  #elif defined __STDC_VERSION__ && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201710
    #define CVERSION 2017
  #elif defined __STDC_VERSION__ && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112
    #define CVERSION 2011
  #elif defined __STDC_VERSION__ && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901
    #define CVERSION 1999
  #elif defined __STDC_VERSION__ && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199409
    #define CVERSION 1994
  #else
    #define CVERSION 1989
#else
    // Pre-standard C
    #define CVERSION 1972
#endif
```

---

"warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]" implies using and old compiler.  As `"%zu"` was introduced in C99.  A possible  conditional compilation.

```
size_t n;
printf("Enter number of numbers: ");
#if defined __STDC__ && defined __STDC_VERSION__ && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901
  scanf("%zu", &n);
#else
  unsigned long t;
  scanf("%lu", &t);
  n = t;
#endif
```

Or with the code at the top:

```
#if CVERSION >= 1999
  scanf("%zu", &n);
#else
  unsigned long t;
  scanf("%lu", &t);
  n = t;
#endif
```

Comment: Apparently my compiler doesn't define `__STDC__`. The `__STD_VERSION__` is `201112`.

Comment: If a compiler does not define `__STDC__` then it is not conforming to any C standard and you are on your own.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, didn't copy-paste the code you posted correctly. `__STDC__` is defined as `1` and thus `CVERSION` is `2011`.